# TextView height stretches in parent with gravity right. why?

Tags: android, xml, gravity

I am making chat activity and having issues with right chat bubble. As you can see in the image below. `TextView` stretches height wise. According to my thinking it should be stretching width wise first then if space is full it should stretch height wise. Please suggest me if it is possible with xml or not. I have seen java code solution but i want to find a solution in xml first.

[image]

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="20" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:gravity="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bubble_sent"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_msg_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_message_time"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_message_time"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Lorem"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_message_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_msg_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
            android:text="00:33"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAppGray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you giving `android:layout_weight` **80** and **20** instead of giving simply **4** and **1**.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Not 3 and 1, it should be 4 and 1

Comment: just for my understanding. i want to give 80% weight to layout.

Comment: @BilalHaider then why your `android:text="Lorem"` is not showing on screen ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna that's the issue that i am facing. that's why asked it here. when i write more text it stretches in height but is not visible.

Comment: @BilalHaider Better use **0.8** and **0.2** then. Any ways instead of adding `gravity` to `RelativeLayout`, why aren't you using `alignParentRight` and `alignParentTop` in child?

Comment: probably its taking image hight..  `ic_bubble_sent` is nine-patch image?

Comment: @vrundpurohit yes it's a nine-patch image. not any issue with image.

Comment: @Rehan are you suggesting to set `txt_message_time` `alignParentRight`?

Comment: @BilalHaider Yes that is what I mean, Or simply use `LinearLayout` in place of `RelativeLayout`, if you want to use `gravity` in parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your two `TextView` with this,

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_msg_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Lorem"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_message_time"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_message_time"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_message_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:33"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_msg_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

I removed all unnecessary alignments from first `TextView`.

**UPDATE** 
The overall layout looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:gravity="right">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_msg_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Lorem"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_message_time"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_message_time"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_message_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="00:33"

                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_msg_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note : I removed your background for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but this is stretching there parent `RelativeLayout` to fill it's parent `LinearLayout`. i want `RelativeLayout` to wrap its content.

Comment: No, I didn't understand what you are saying, This won't affect any parent layout, It's still inside your `RelativeLayout`

Comment: see above image. this is happening after your suggestion.

Comment: I want `RelativeLayout` to wrap it's content. It is filling it's parent and not wrapping its child.

Comment: Can you elaborate what element are you announcing as **It's**.

Comment: I am referring to `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @BilalHaider The relative layout is wrapping 2 textviews. as well as filling it's parent, which is set to wrap_content. and That linear layout is also filled 3/4 spaces. Everything seems fine. I really apologize for not understanding what hierarchy you are searching for. May be my mind is hanged today :D. I have to leave now, Plz comment more clearly as you can, I will fix that soon as possible.

Comment: "The relative layout is wrapping 2 textviews. as well as filling it's parent," it should wrap 2 textViews but should not fill its parent. how can this both be possible at the same time?

Comment: It's not wrapping the it's contents well, we can give paddingleft in parent linearlayout of that relativelayout to make it abit viewable.